# SOAP Server and Client in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to develop a very simple SOAP server and Client in PHP.
The goal is to receive content from a remote XML-document as the source.

This is what I have done so far, I need help how to extract data from an XML file instead, as it is now, from an ordinary array.
This is the function found in inventory_functions.php that is fetching from an array, how can it be changed to fetch from the XML file instead?
Am I on the right track, is this a SOAP setup?

```
  function getItemCount($upc) {

    // In reality, this data would be coming from a database

    $items = array('12345'=>5,'19283'=>100,'23489'=>'234');

    // Return the requested value

    return $items[$upc];

}
```

This is the code for the server:

```
  // Load the database

  require 'inventory_functions.php';

  // Turn off WSDL cache

  ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

  // Create a new SoapServer object with inventory.wsdl

  $server = new SoapServer("inventory.wsdl");

  // Register the getItemCount function

  $server->addFunction("getItemCount");

  // Start the handle

  $server->handle();
```

This is the code for the client:

```
// Turn off WSDL cache

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

// Create a new SOAPClient object

$client = new SoapClient("inventory.wsdl");

// Get the value for the function getItemCount with the ID of 12345

$getItemCount = $client->getItemCount('12345');

// Print the result

echo ($getItemCount);
```

Please help!

Comment: could you be more specific about where the XML is involved ? is it the database in your comment "// In reality, this data would be coming from a database"

Comment: The XML-document has not been developed yet, the idea is that I will fetch content from any given XML source. I just need to use an XML document as data source instead of a normal array as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not a SOAP server problem, it is about XML access.

Assuming your XML contains the same data as the array quoted in example, and you can get [simpleXML](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) on your server:

```
//load your xml file into $xmlStr, with file_get_contents() or whatever.
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$items = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);
```

You can also use [DomDocument](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead, it has a DOM API, so if you're familiar with HTML DOM it will be easier.

In your example it has one big advantage, you can search result directly inside the XML using Xpath, instead of using array.

Comment: Thanks! This looks interesting. So the $items above is now an ordinary array? Does the rest of the code look fine (I am a novice in SOAP)?

Comment: This was the exact solution to getting XML data into a SOAP envelope from the client to the server.  Thanks! +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

for better use you can try soap client like http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/ for better flexibility.